# `rows_update` Error: `x` key values are not unique

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to use `rows_update` with non-unique x values?

```r
library(dplyr)

x = tibble(x = c(1,1,2), z = "x")
y = tibble(x = c(1,2), z = "y") 
   
rows_update(x, y)
#> Matching, by = "x"
#> Error: `x` key values are not unique.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: What is your expected output in this case? Do you want to update both the rows or just the first one?

Comment: I'd like to update all three rows in X

Comment: Then I doubt if `rows_update` is the right function. Why not `merge(x, y, by = 'x')` ?

Comment: the only thing I don't like about the merge approach is that I don't want to add a new columns and rename

Comment: also i don't want to lose non-matching rows in x

Comment: I have the same issue but using rows_patch which feels even more like it should allow non unique keys since it only updates when x is NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `rows_update` requires key variables to take unique values. If the constraint is to use `rows_update` without creating extra-columns, I would propose:

```
x %>% distinct() %>% 
rows_update(y, by = "x") %>% 
right_join(x %>% select(x), by = "x")
```

Comment: hopefully they remove that constraint, or add options to get around it soon! thanks for the answer